# _mm_mul_epu32 and _mm_mullo_epi32 on arm neon

Tags: c, linux, arm, simd, neon

I am working on a application to port SSE code to Neon.

I see the intrinsics `_mm_mullo_epi32` and `_mm_mul_epu32` in SSE.

Do we have an equivalent of Neon for these ?

Comment: For ARM32 or ARM64?

Comment: Have a look at how SIMDe emulates that for ARM/AArch64.  https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/.  https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/blob/2fdc9a5e5f078cb11107bdd5c79b6a5fa6d8bf43/simde/x86/sse2.h#L4161.  Or just use SIMDe's header-emulations to compile your whole program, and work on speedup up any hotspots where ARM-specific code use a better with a strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `_mm_mullo_epi32` is `vmulq_s32`

`_mm_mul_epu32` is a bit tricky, no single NEON instruction does the job.
Still, the workaround is not that bad, only needs 3 instructions. Two `vmovn_u64` instructions to discard every 2-nd lane of the arguments, followed by `vmull_u32` to multiply 32-bit lanes into 64-bit ones.

Comment: could you share the steps for mul_epu32 implementation

Comment: @sunmoon Apply `vmovn_u64` to both arguments. If your compiler complains about incompatible types (only some of them do), use `vreinterpretq_u64_u32` or similar intrinsic for the argument (these compile into no instructions i.e. they are free performance wise). Then return `vmull_u32` of these 2 `uint32x2_t` vectors produced by two `vmovn_u64` instructions. See the documentation for more info: https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics